# How to remove [ ] from testDatabase

Tags: haskell

How to fix this error? I know that testDatabase have an additional [ ] but how to remove the [ ] without triggering error? I am stuck for a few days...

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Spa -> [Spa]'
              with actual type `[Spa]'
* In the second argument of `(.)', namely `testDatabase'
  In the second argument of `(.)', namely
    `averageRating . testDatabase'
  In the first argument of `filter', namely
    `((>= 8) . averageRating . testDatabase)'
```

My code below

```
data Spa = Spa SpaID Brand Area Stars [(Service, LevelRating)]
                  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

type spaID = String
type Brand = String
type Area = String
type Stars = Int
type Service =  String 
type LevelRating = Int 

testDatabase :: [Spa]

-- spa service level rating
getServiceLevelRating :: Spa -> [(Service, LevelRating)]
getServiceLevelRating (Spa _ _ _ _ s) = s

--making spa average level rating
averagelvRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averagelvRating [] = 0
averagelvRating avglvrating = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd avglvrating)) / (fromIntegral(length avglvrating))

--making spa average list
averageRating :: [Spa] -> [Float]
averageRating = (<$>) (averagelvRating . getServiceLevelRating)

--filtering
spaLevelRating :: Float -> [Spa] -> [Spa]
spaLevelRating levelRating = filter ((>=8) . averageRating . testDatabase)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using composition `(.)` with non-function operand `testDatabase`. You probably meant

```
spaLevelRating levelRating = filter ((>=8) . averageRating) testDatabase
```

Comment: It gives me two error instead.  * Couldn't match expected type `[Restaurant] -> [Restaurant]'
              with actual type `[[Restaurant]]'
* Possible cause: `filter' is applied to too many arguments
  In the expression: filter ((>= 8) . averageRating) testDatabase
  In an equation for `restaurantLevelRating':
      restaurantLevelRating levelRating
        = filter ((>= 8) . averageRating) testDatabase

Comment: * Couldn't match type `Restaurant' with `[Restaurant]'
  Expected type: [[Restaurant]]
    Actual type: [Restaurant]
* In the second argument of `filter', namely `testDatabase'
  In the expression: filter ((>= 8) . averageRating) testDatabase
  In an equation for `restaurantLevelRating':
      restaurantLevelRating levelRating
        = filter ((>= 8) . averageRating) testDatabase

Answer (score 1):

Use `fmap` instead of `(<$>)` if you're not going to use it as an infix operator:

```
averageRating = fmap (averagelvRating . getServiceLevelRating)
```

or simply `map` to make it clear that we mean the list functor. Since `getServiceLevelRating` is a field getter, you may want to use record syntax to get them as native parts of the data type. And since we're doing averages on integers, the `div` operator avoids the need for `fromIntegral`.

```hs
import Data.List (genericLength)

data Spa = Spa
  { spaID :: SpaID
  , spaBrand :: Brand
  , spaArea :: Area
  , spaStars :: Stars 
  , spaServiceLevelRating :: [(Service, LevelRating)]
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

average :: Integral a => [a] -> a
average xs = sum xs `div` genericLength xs

averageLevelRating :: Spa -> LevelRating
averageLevelRating = average . map snd . spaServiceLevelRating
```

This way `average` is a little more reusable and filtering becomes

```
filter ((>= 8) . averageLevelRating) testDatabase
```